# _programmatically_ find all supported ciphers for https urlconnections

Tags: java, encryption, https

Ok, this sounds like a trivial thing but i can't figure out how to do it, because there is so much confusion when searching here/google.

How can I programatically find all supported ciphers which can be used for an URLConnection? For example "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256".

Most answers on similar questions suggest to "just read the oracle documentation" but I'm using 3rd party JVMs which are in general compatible to Java4, 5 or 6 but normally have only one security provider which has a handful of ciphers added by the jvm-vendor. They also are using proprietary security and policy files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
SSLSocketFactory ssf = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
String[] enabledCiphers = ssf.getDefaultCipherSuites();
```

Comment: Thank you, thats it. When creating an emptysocket with that factory, it is also possible to see enabled as well as all supported Ciphers. Maybe for someone it is also interesting, how to enable supported, but not enabled cyphersuites: You can extend SSLSocketFactory, using a (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault() as an instance there and in all createSocket method you have to override, you can just call factory.createSocket.